# What to do with a post that contains personal information?

Tags: support

In Howard Butler's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/389409/81403), he gives out his email address.

I was tought in Pre-K not to publish personal information on the internet.

Shouldn't there be something in the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) that advises against posting personal information?

Comment: On another note, we should generally discourage any way of contact information inside an answer; we want the solution to be on our site, not outside of it.

Comment: I'd note another similar situation is if a password is given out by accident - its happened before on SF.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, as ♦ moderators, we:

1. Delete the post.
2. Edit out the sensitive information.
3. Contact a SE developer to remove the information from the revision history.
4. Undelete the post.

So, as a registered user or 10K+ user, **you should edit out the sensitive info and flag the answer, letting us know** what's going on.  We'll take it from there.

Comment: I'll also do that..., thanks.

Answer (score 7):

A lot of users do this, adding a little tagline/Signature to their posts. Usually these are first time answers. The best thing to do, which I do, is to simply press **Edit** and then remove it. As a 2k+ user, you have the ability to help users clean this out.

After removing it, simply leave a little comment advising them to fill out their email on their **Profile**, instead of adding it on there. You may want to notify a moderator via flag or chat, so they can clean it out.

Comment: I'll do that, Thanks.

Comment: Good point! It's not just 10k+ users who can help with this but anyone with edit access. Furthermore, even users without edit access can and should still flag the answer for a moderator. :)